# Just Exec SP works but Insert into table Exec SP goes in infinite loop

Tags: t-sql

Question 1)

We are planning to turn off XP CMDSHELL in SQL. Is there any alternative to the method I am using below:

Question 2)

Below SP

1.Creates new SQL Job every time
2.Runs the CMD command passed to it from SP param 
3.Finally SP return result

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CMDSHELL_ALTERNATIVE]    Script Date: 5/8/2020 5:44:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CMDSHELL_ALTERNATIVE]

    @Command varchar(200),
    @InvokedBySP varchar(100) = 'AdhocCalling'
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @OutputFileName varchar(max)
DECLARE @OutputFilePath varchar(max)
DECLARE @JobOutcome int = 5
DECLARE @JobMessage varchar(max)
DECLARE @TodayDate DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @JobExecutionTime DATETIME
DECLARE @RandomeNumber BIGINT = CAST(RAND() * 1000000 AS BIGINT)
DECLARE @JobName varchar(100) = 'CMDSHELL_JOB_'+ CAST(@TodayDate AS VARCHAR)+'_'+CAST(@RandomeNumber AS VARCHAR)
SET @OutputFilePath ='C:\Users\OutputFiles\'
SET @OutputFileName = @JobName+'.txt'
DECLARE @FullOutputFilePathName varchar(max) = @OutputFilePath+@OutputFileName
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=@JobName, 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=@JobName, @server_name = N'(local)'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=@JobName, @step_name=N'step-1', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
        @command=N'', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @output_file_name=N'', 
        @flags=0

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=@JobName, 
        @enabled=1, 
        @start_step_id=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'', 
        @notify_page_operator_name=N''

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep 
    @job_name=@JobName, 
    @step_id=1 , 
    @command=@Command, 
    @output_file_name=@FullOutputFilePathName

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @JobName

SELECT distinct @JobOutcome =  SJH.run_status
FROM msdb..sysjobhistory SJH, msdb..sysjobs SJ
WHERE SJH.job_id = SJ.job_id and SJ.Name = @JobName 

WHILE (@JobOutcome != 3 AND @JobOutcome > 1)
 BEGIN
    print 'In a delay loop'
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
    SELECT distinct @JobOutcome =  SJH.run_status
    FROM msdb..sysjobhistory SJH, msdb..sysjobs SJ
    WHERE SJH.job_id = SJ.job_id and SJ.Name = @JobName
 END

SET @JobExecutionTime = GETDATE()
SELECT @JobMessage = message FROM msdb..sysjobhistory SJH, msdb..sysjobs SJ
WHERE SJH.job_id = SJ.job_id and SJ.Name = @JobName
AND step_id = 1

IF @JobOutcome = 1
    BEGIN
    print 'Job successfull'
    Declare @BulkInsertCommand varchar(max)
    CREATE TABLE #temp (results NVARCHAR(755))
    SET @BulkInsertCommand = 

    'BULK INSERT #temp
    FROM ''' + @FullOutputFilePathName +'''
    WITH
    (
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    DataFileType=''widechar''
    )'

    EXEC (@BulkInsertCommand)
    Select results from #temp
    execute Test.dbo.CLR_CMDSHELL_LOGGING @JobName,@InvokedBySP,@Command,@JobExecutionTime,'Job Successfull',@JobMessage
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
    print 'Dynamic Job failed'
    execute Test.dbo.CLR_CMDSHELL_LOGGING @JobName,@InvokedBySP,@Command,@JobExecutionTime,'Job Failed',@JobMessage
    END
IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = @JobName)
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=@JobName


END
```

Now I run above SP using below code -

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(100)
SET @cmd = 'DIR /B C:\Users\Test'
--DECLARE @dirTable TABLE (oPut VARCHAR(max))
--insert @dirTable
EXEC [dbo].CMDSHELL_ALTERNATIVE @cmd
--select * from @dirTable
```

Result without Insert

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j0ZC.png)

Problem

Code above without insert works fine, returns result quickly. But when Insert statement is uncommented, SP runs forever.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thnf5.png)`enter code here`

I can't figure out exactly where the blocking is. Any alternative/fix in above?

Comment: Perhaps if you output the value of `@JobOutcome` in the wait loop you'll have a hint. That you need to use `distinct` to get the value points to one issue.

Comment: Thanks i did that its printing the default assigned value 5 all the time.

Comment: Adding to that meanwhile the code is running i am unable to open job monitor window its giving error lock request elapsed.

Comment: Even sysjobhistory doesnt have any records related to that job